# Adding a search by zip code in a custom Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zipcode

First I would like to say that I am new to this site, never worked with Google Maps API and have an intermediate knowledge of JavaScript.

**What I have done:**
I put together a custom 'store locator' by adding locations to a Google 'my maps'.  I then created a web page with a drop down menu and depending on the location you select from the drop down, it changes the the SRC for the iFrame holding the map.  So when the page loads you see a larger scale map and by selecting specific locations, it will change the map to that specific location (zoom and crop).

**What I need to do:**
What I need to do now to complete this map is to add a 'search by zip code' which will allow the user to put in their zip code and have the web page return a list of the closest locations and hopefully their distances.

Does anyone have an idea if I will be able to add the 'search by zip' functionality to my custom Google map?

There really isn't much to my code to post, but if it will help, I'll gladly do so.  The current functionality of my map works great, the problem is that I don't know where to begin adding the zip code search.

Here is a link to the page that I am referring to: http://74.53.82.155/store-locator.htm

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
gnrlchaos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the geonames web service that [returns locations from zip codes](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeLookupJSON). Here's a quick example of how to use that web service with dojo.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = { parseOnLoad: true }</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dojo-release-1.3.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
                function getPlace() {
        var zip = dojo.byId('zipcode').value;
        console.log('zip is ', zip);
        //use country code to get results for a specific country
        //var gn_url = 'http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=' + zip + '&country=US';
        var gn_url = 'http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=' + zip;
        console.log(gn_url);
        dojo.io.script.get({
          url: gn_url, 
          callbackParamName: "callback",
          load:function(response, io) { 
            console.log('got json.'); 
            console.dir(response); 
            places = response.postalcodes; 
            var infos = []
            dojo.forEach(places, function(p, i) {
                infos[i] = p.placeName + ', ' + p.adminName1 + ', Lat: ' + p.lat + '; Long: ' + p.lng + '<br />';
            });
                dojo.byId('postalCode').innerHTML = infos.join('');
          }, 
          error:errorCb
        });   
        }

        function errorCb(type, data, evt){
                debug(data);
        }
         </script>
     </head>
     <body class="tundra">
    Enter a zip code: <input id="zipcode" type="text" /> <button onclick="getPlace(); return false;" value="Find Place.">Find Place.</button>
      <div>Places:</div><div id="postalCode"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to interact with an embedded Google Map in the way that you want.  The best option would be to create your own map with the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).  Google has some great [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html) and [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/index.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

hey, i'm working on a similar search too.  i found a pretty good discussion of the math involved, as well as links to queries and formulas, here:  http://uclue.com/?xq=2861.  hope this helps.